# Assign value to an HTML attribute in Odoo website

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

I am working on an integration with Odoo, that makes use of a JavaScript applet on the website to read the attributes of an HTML element and use them to identify the logged in customer.

Unfortunately, I am a noob at front-end development and cannot get it to work.

An element like this does output the email address, for instance me@example.com, of the user onto the web page:
`<div t-raw="request and request.env.user.partner_id.email"/>`

How can I assign the value of *request.env.user.partner_id.email* to the *data-email* attribute, instead of the hard-coded email address, kin the identification element here below??

```
<div
    id="customer-identification-html-element"
    data-authenticated="true"
    data-email="me@example.com"
>
</div>
```

I tried setting *data-email="request.env.user.partner_id.email"*, but then the string is sent as is to the third party, without resolving its value.

I also tried *t-att-data-email="request.env.user.paretner_id.email"*, to get an error while rendering the template.

Comment: try with `t-attf-data-email` (note that there is f after att) also you can `t-set='foo'` to set it to a variable and call that variable in `t-attf...`

Comment: Thanks @kingofsevens, That's how I solved it. I wrote the attributes as:

```
id="customer-identification-html-element"
data-authenticated="true"
t-attf-data-email="{{request and request.env.user.partner_id.email}}"
```

Using the curly braces and prefixing `t-attf-` was the solution. What's inside the double curly braces is then processed as code and resolves to the email address of the logged in customer, and `t-attf-` is stripped while rendering, so the external service sees it as data-email="me@example.com"

Thank you also for mentioning `t-set`, really useful!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [kingofsevens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3986110/kingofsevens),

Prefixing `t-attf-` and using the curly braces was the solution. I wrote the `<div>` element as:

```
<div
    id="customer-identification-html-element"
    data-authenticated="true"
    t-attf-data-email="{{request and request.env.user.partner_id.email}}"
>
</div>
```

What's inside the double curly braces is then processed as code and resolves to the email address of the logged in customer, and `t-attf-` is stripped while rendering, so the external service sees it as `data-email="me@example.com"`

Thank you also for mentioning `t-set`, really useful!

PS: thanks @rob for mentioning the invalid HTML, corrected it!